# How to undo image scaled in xcode

Tags: xcode4

Im working on application in which i scale ,rotate and translate image.
Im saving angle while rotating for undo. Similarly im saving centerX and centerY for translation undo. But saving scaling parameter results into undesired results.
Please tell me how to undo scaled image.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CGFloat)getCurrentScale {
    CGAffineTransform t = image.transform;
    CGFloat a, c, b, d;
    a = t.a;
    c = t.c;
    b = t.b;
    d = t.d;
    CGFloat scaleX = sqrt(powf(a,2)+powf(c,2));
    return scaleX;
}
```

Comment: call this function from state end of pinch recognizer function